# Cake Php and PhpStorm Expecting statement

Tags: cakephp, phpstorm

I have issue with ending foreach line in Php Storm (cake php 2.4.6)

This is my code in ctp file:

```
<h2>List Users</h2>

<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Name:</td>
        <td>Password:</td>
    </tr>
<?php foreach ($users  as $user); ?>

<tr>
    <td><?php echo $this->$user['User']['username'];?> </td>
    <td><?php echo $this->$user['User']['password'];?></td>
</tr>
    <?php endforeach ?>
</table>
```

On this line I have error:

```
<?php endforeach ?>
```

(Expecting statement)

What is wrong with this ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Foreach should start with colon `:`

```
<?php foreach ($users  as $user): ?> //Should be colon not semi-colon

<?php endforeach ?>
```

*[Reference](http://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php)*.

Comment: You don't need the semicolon when using a closing PHP tag.

Answer (score 3):

You have put a semicolon here

```
<?php foreach ($users  as $user); ?>
```

but it should be a colon:

```
<?php foreach ($users  as $user): ?>
```

The semicolon ends the whole loop in this line.